# graphing multiple series with the same y axis on an html page

Tags: javascript, html, dojo, google-visualization

For the last couple of days, I have been attempting to find a tool that allows me to plot two graphs on the same that, with the same y-axis and different x-axis co-ordinates. In particular, I would like to graph a curve and a line running through that curve at a specific point on the x-axis.

The x and y points for the curve are already know and will be hard coded into the page, but the value for the x co-ordinate for the line will be generated by a program.

I was hoping to find a tool where I could simply do something like this:

Plot this for the curve,

x {0,
0.05,
0.1,
0.15,
0.2,
0.25,
0.3,
0.35,
0.4,
0.45,
0.5,
0.55,
0.6,
0.65,
0.7,
0.75,
0.8,
0.85,
0.9,
0.95,
1
}

y {0,
9.6,
6,
2.5,
1,
0.6,
0.3,
0.24,
0.1,
0.08,
0.02,
0.009,
0.0009,
0.00009,
0.000009,
0.0000009,
0,
0,
0,
0,
0
}

And then plot something like this for the line;

x {estRisk, estRisk}

y {0, 10}

where the "estRisk" will be a value between 0 and 1

I was directed to look into google charts and dojo by my boss and some of my more experienced colleagues, but so far with both of those tools, I have only been able to find numerous tutorials and examples that allow you to plot multiple series with a common x-axis but not with a common y-axis.

Is what I am looking for possible with any of those tools? Are there any other tools that would allow me to do this? Should I just call it a day and give up on this particular venture?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want something that looks like this:

[image: Sample Chart]

The following code will create it:

```
function drawVisualization() {
  //Set EstRisk Variable

  var EstRisk = 0.23;

  // Create and populate the data table.
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable()
  data.addColumn('number', 'X');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Y');
  data.addColumn('number', 'EstRisk');
  data.addRows([
    [0, 0, null],
    [0.05, 9.6, null],
    [0.1, 6, null],
    [0.15, 2.5, null],
    [0.2, 1, null],
    [0.25, 0.6, null],
    [0.3, 0.3, null],
    [0.35, 0.24, null],
    [0.4, 0.1, null],
    [0.45, 0.08, null],
    [0.5, 0.02, null],
    [0.55, 0.009, null],
    [0.6, 0.0009, null],
    [0.65, 0.00009, null],
    [0.7, 0.000009, null],
    [0.75, 0.0000009, null],
    [0.8, 0, null],
    [0.85, 0, null],
    [0.9, 0, null],
    [0.95, 0, null],
    [1, 0, null],
  ]);

  data.addRows([
    [EstRisk, null, 0],
    [EstRisk, null, 10],
  ]);

  // Create and draw the visualization.
  new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
      draw(data, {curveType: "function",
                  width: 500, height: 400}
          );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something similar can be achieved in Dojo as follows:

```
require(["dojo/domReady", "dojox/charting/Chart", "dojox/charting/axis2d/Default",
        "dojox/charting/plot2d/Lines", "dojox/charting/themes/Julie"],
    function(domReady, Chart, Axis, Lines, Theme){
        domReady(function(){
            var estrisk = 0.23;
            var chart = new Chart("chart");
            chart.addAxis("x", {type: Axis});
            chart.addAxis("y", {type: Axis, vertical: true });
            chart.addPlot("curve", {type: Lines, tension: "x"});
            chart.addPlot("line", {type: Lines });
            chart.addSeries("1", 
                         [ {x:0,y:0}, {x:0.05,y:9.6}, {x:0.1,y:6},
                           {x:0.15,y:2.5}, {x:0.2,y:1}, {x:0.25,y:0.6},
                           {x:0.3,y:0.3}, {x:0.35,y:0.24}, {x:0.4,y:0.1},          
                           {x:0.45,y:0.08}, {x:0.5,y:0.02}, {x:0.55,y:0.009},
                           {x:0.6,y:0.0009}, {x:0.65,y:0.00009}, {x:0.7,y:0.000009},
                           {x:0.75,y:0.0000009}, {x:0.8,y:0}, {x:0.85,y:0},
                           {x:0.9,y:0}, {x:0.95,y:0}, {x:1,y:0} ], 
                       { plot: "curve"});
            chart.addSeries("2",
                         [ { x: estrisk, y: 0}, { x: estrisk, y: 10} ], 
                       { plot: "line" });
            chart.render();
        });
    }
);
```

Comment: Kalada, consider flagging the question as answered if this provides the solution you needed.